# PHP Mailer -> PDF to Email provides blank PDF as attachment

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer

I am using PHP Mailer to basically send a interactive PDF to an email address. This works locally calling the script from the PDF to the server, but does not work when the PDF is completed on the server.

Code is below:

```
<?php
if(!isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
    echo "The Application could not be sent. Please save the PDF and email it manually.";
    exit;
}
echo "<html><head></head><body><img src='loading.gif'>";

//Create PDF file with data
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$pdf = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;

 $file = $semi_rand . ".pdf"; 
 $handle = fopen($file, 'w+');
 fwrite($handle, $pdf);   
 fclose($handle);
//

require_once('class/class.phpmailer.php');
include("class/class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail = new PHPMailer(false); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
$mail -> CharSet = "UTF-8";

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

try {
  $mail->Host       = "HOST"; // SMTP server
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
  $mail->Host       = "HOST";
  $mail->Port       = 465;
  $mail->Username   = "USERNAME";
  $mail->Password   = "PASSWORD";
  $mail->AddAddress('TO ADDRESS');
  $mail->SetFrom('FROM ADDRESS');
  $mail->Subject = 'SUBJECT';
  $mail->Body = 'Please see attachment';
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->AddAttachment($file); // attachment
  $mail->Send();

  //Delete the temp pdf file then redirect to the success page
  // unlink($file);
  echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL="1.1.1.1">';    
  exit;    
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  //you can either report the errors here or redirect them to an error page
  //using the above META tag
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
  //Verify the temporary pdf file got deleted
  unlink($file);
?>
```

Is there something I am missing? All values for the $mail (host, username, password etc) are correct - but when it creates the PDF to send, it only comes through as < 1kb. My PDF calls this PHP file on submit.

Comment: By interactive, do you mean a fillable form PDF? When you say it works locally, what exactly is the content of emailed PDF -webpage content or just text/numeric data? Does user press a button on PDF? If so, why not just use [Adobe form submit action event](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/form-submit-e-mail-demystified) to send email to particular recipient.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create PDFs like simple txt or csv files with `fwrite`. It is a more sophisticated file type.

Look into [DomPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) which for your setting may look somewhat like the below (assuming `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is an html document):

```
require("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$semi_rand = md5(time());
$pdf = file_get_contents('http://www.pdfpage.com/');
$file = $semi_rand . ".pdf"; 

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($pdf);
$dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($file,  array('Attachment' => '0'));

...
// USE $file as needed in email attachment
```

Comment: I replaced //Create PDF file with data and below with your code above and downloaded the dompdf library - nothing happens on submit. Not sure what you mean re $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is an html document? I am just wanting to save and send the interactive PDF via email as a PDF

Comment: He's saying that `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` does not contain PDF data, so trying to treat it as a PDF makes no sense and will not work.

Comment: Forgive me, it seems [$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) is the output of the form data in a concatenated `key1=value1&...` format. To create a PDF, you will need to create an HTML page of posted data, possibly re-use form page with input values filled then send that long string as `$pdf` into $dompdf.

Comment: My original code works just fine if I submit from the same PDF locally. It still posts to the server PHP and I receive it fine, just doesnt work when the PDF is on the server - any ideas/reason behind that?